# Pass a wifi dongle directly to a vmware guest and connect to 2 separate wifi connections through the host and guest?

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, virtual-machine, vpn, vmware

I am running `Linux Mint 18.3` with `osx High Seria`

Inside the guest VM I have disabled network and connected a wifi dongle and passed this directly to the vm.

I have installed the correct drivers and can see the connection in the network tab.

This particular dongle has its own software to find the wifi networks. However no networks appear. I know that there are networks as the host is connected to a network.

So why can't the guest detect any networks?

[image]
[image]
[image]